# "Totally disconnected" analogue of a classical result from functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, commutative-algebra, compactness

Consider the following result:

> Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space.  Then $x \mapsto \mathfrak m_x = \{ f \in \mathscr C(X) : f(x) = 0 \}$ defines a bijection $X \rightarrow \operatorname{m-spec} \mathscr C(X)$, where $\mathscr C(X)$ is the ring of continuous functions $X \rightarrow \mathbb C$.

See for example my previous answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1171142/x-compact-hausdorff-space-characterize-the-maximal-ideals-of-cx).  There is an interesting analogue of these statement which I have seen mentioned in a number-theoretic context:

> Let $X$ be a compact totally disconnected Hausdorff space.  Then $x \mapsto \mathfrak p_x = \{ f \in \mathscr C^{\infty}(X) : f(x) = 0 \}$ defines a bijection of sets $X \rightarrow \operatorname{spec} \mathscr C^{\infty}(X)$, where $\mathscr C^{\infty}(X)$ is the ring of locally constant functions $X \rightarrow \mathbb Q$.

Is this result true?  It seems strange that $\mathscr C^{\infty}(X)$ should have no nonmaximal prime ideals.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  $\space$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed true.  Let me provide a bit more context for this result. First of all, it remains true with $\mathbb{Q}$ replaced by any field $K$.  To prove this, it suffices by your argument to prove that any prime ideal is contained in $\mathfrak{p}_x$ for some $x$.  If $I$ is an ideal which is not contained in any $\mathfrak{p}_x$, choose functions $f_x\in I$ for each $x$ such that $f_x(x)\neq 0$.  Let $U_x$ be the support of $f_x$, which is not just closed but clopen because $f_x$ is locally constant.  By compactness, finitely many of the $U_x$ cover $X$, say $U_{x_1},\dots U_{x_n}$.  We may furthermore shrink these sets to clopen sets $V_{1},\dots,V_{n}$ which are disjoint and cover $X$ (let $V_{i}=U_{x_i}\setminus\bigcup_{j<i}U_{x_j}$).  Then $1_{V_i}$ is a multiple of $f_{x_i}$ (multiply by a function which is $1/f_{x_i}$ on $V_i$ and $0$ elsewhere), and so $1=\sum_i 1_{V_i}\in I$.

Also, the map $f:X \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} \mathscr C^{\infty}(X)$ is not just a bijection but a homeomorphism.  This follows from the fact clopen sets generate the topology of $X$ and the image of a clopen set is clopen (by considering characteristic functions of clopen sets and the open subsets of $\operatorname{Spec} \mathscr C^{\infty}(X)$ they define).

It is customary to consider this result primarily in the case $K=\mathbb{F}_2$.  In that case, the ring $B$ of locally constant functions $X\to K$ can be identified with the Boolean algebra of clopen subsets of $X$ (identify a clopen subset with its characteristic function).  The theorem that the natural map $X\to\operatorname{Spec} B$ is a homeomorphism is then part of *Stone duality*, an equivalence of categories between the category of totally disconnected compact Hausdorff spaces and the category of Boolean algebras.

(In fact, this equivalence of categories holds more generally over any field $K$, if you replace "Boolean algebras" with "$K$-algebras generated by idempotents".)

Comment: Thank you.  That is so interesting how the profinite topology coincides with the Zariski topology.  Usually you expect Hausdorff topologies to be completely different from Zariski.

Comment: In fact, this is in some sense the only way the Zariski topology can be Hausdorff: if Spec of a ring is Hausdorff (or even $T_1$), it is automatically totally disconnected.

Comment: If $R$ is a reduced $\mathbb Q$-algebra and $X = \operatorname{Spec}R$ is Hausdorff, then is $R$ isomorphic to the space of locally constant functions on $X$?

Comment: No (consider when $R$ is a field!), but it is true if you additionally assume that every residue field of $R$ is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: As a sketch of a proof, let $S$ be the ring of locally constant functions on $X$.  There is a natural homomorphism $R\to S$ (every element of $R$ determines a locally constant function by taking the images in the residue fields).  This homomorphism is surjective because $S$ is generated by the characteristic functions of clopen sets, and injective because $R$ is reduced.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R = \mathscr C^{\infty}(X)$.   The argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1171191) carries over identically to show that every ideal of $R$ is contained in a maximal ideal of the form $\mathfrak p = \{ f \in R : f(x) = 0\}$ for some $x \in X$.  So we just need to show that no such prime $\mathfrak p$ contains a proper prime ideal.  This is the same as saying that $R_{\mathfrak p}$ is a zero dimensional local ring, i.e. every element of $\mathfrak p R_{\mathfrak p}$ is nilpotent.

But since $R$ is reduced, so is $R_{\mathfrak p}$, so this is equivalent to saying that $\mathfrak p R_{\mathfrak p} = 0$, i.e. $R_{\mathfrak p}$ is a field.  It suffices to show that the image of $\mathfrak p$ in $R_{\mathfrak p}$ is zero, i.e. if $f \in \mathfrak p$, then there exists an $h \in R - \mathfrak p$ such that $fh = 0$.

Since $f \in \mathfrak p$ and locally constant, it is zero in a compact open neighborhood $V$ of $x$.  The complement of this compact neighborhood is also open, and one can take $h$ to be nonzero on $V$, and zero on the complement of $V$.